# Callback using ObservableObject with a Collection on windows phone Viewmodels

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I've an issue in some code I'm writing which is attempting to use the `ObservableObject` within Databinding when using a list of items.  I have a model view which when binding to a single `ObservableObject` is fine, but when I bind to a `List` of `ObservableObject` it stops working when I update one the items.

So I have the following;

```
public class SongViewModel : ObservableObject
```

and this in a separate class;

```
public class AlbumViewModel 
    {
        ObservableCollection<SongViewModel> _songs = new ObservableCollection<SongViewModel>();
```

Binding to a `LongListSelection` which uses the `SongViewModel` as the data source is working OK, however is I bind to the `AlbumViewModel` the update callback stops working and the UI isn't updated.

I've created a small windows phone 8 solution to demonstrate the issue:

http://moonmirage.no-ip.org/wcf_phone.zip

Comment: Fixed it.  My databinding was incorrect in the xaml file.